# How would PhD Admissions committee read Statements of Purpose?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am referring to PhD admissions in US here. I've been always told that SoP's are important and require some commitment in writing. But in the meantime I hear a lot of such voices that PhD programs typically receive tons of applications like 500, so professors in committee would only spend a matter of 5mins-ish long reading about a single application. I am wondering which is the case? I really want to express myself thoroughly in my SoP but I guess a lot of valuable information would not passed to the committee if only under a fast read. (Or is it that I am underestimating their reading speed?)

Answer (score 18):

When I was on my department's graduate committee (which dealt with admissions), I read ~120 applications per year. About half of these are "obviously" not competitive for some reason or other (typically low GPAs) and you might not read all of it very carefully, but I read the SoPs of all competitive applications and I believe that my colleagues did the same. I read them quicker than I would the PhD theses of my students or a scientific paper, but I read them front to back. And they mattered to me and my colleagues.

The message here is: If your application isn't competitive, then you probably don't need to bother with a good SoP. But if your application is competitive, you *also* need a good SoP. Poor SoPs can and do sink applications.

Comment: +1 — this closely matches my own experience of PhD admissions (in Europe).  On a first pass through the applications, I usually just skim some parts, but I certainly read all the “longlisted” applications pretty carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was also wondering as OP how committee read SoP. Would you care to say more about how SoP matters for admission purpose?

Comment: @justhalf There are already many questions about SoPs on this forum, covering all aspects. Search and you will find :-)

Answer (score 2):

The world is what it is, and admissions committees are made up of individuals with their own ideas and priorities. So, you do the best you can on every required element of any application.

If a department really got that many applications there might be some initial weeding out process that reduces the number to a more reasonable level, at least for the first pass. Some applications are incomplete, some flawed. GPA can be a gate some places. Those weeded out may get cursory looks later, provided the more likely pool doesn't yield enough good candidates. Even a quick read of an SoP can be useful in avoiding quick rejection.

So, you write the best SoP you can, detailing academic and career goals and some plan, perhaps, for meeting them. If you do a poor job of this it lowers your expectations.

But, writing an SoP has another objective. It forces you to think about those goals and make them somewhat explicit. *Know Thyself*. A generally useful thing to do.

Comment: Might also be useful to explain the SOP must be both short and very readable/skimmable

Answer (score 0):

These two goals — quality SOP and quick reading — are not mutually exclusive, as @Dawn notes in a comment.  Rather, an excellent SOP will be *easy to read quickly*: it will clearly and succinctly convey your interest in research, interest in the program, and relevant preparation, so that the reader doesn't need more than that 5 minutes to tell that you are a compelling applicant worth further review and consideration for the program.

To that end, I would advise against attempting to explain yourself “thoroughly”. Clarity, concision, and persuasiveness should be your goals, and long-winded SOPs undermine those objectives.